# How to control flow when resource for_each need to fetch data from data source which is having count

Tags: terraform

How to control flow when resource for_each need to fetch data from data source which is having count

Its my requirement to read data from data source only so I have build the code like it

I am getting problem in below line:

```
command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}"
```

I am getting error as :

> ╷ │ Error: Invalid template interpolation value │  │   on
> foreachloop.tf line 79, in resource "null_resource"
> "null_resource_simple": │   79:         command = "echo
> ${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}" │     ├──────────────── │
> │ data.null_data_source.values is tuple with 2 elements │  │ Cannot
> include the given value in a string template: string required.

---

> │ Error: Invalid template interpolation value │  │   on foreachloop.tf
> line 79, in resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple": │   79:
> command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}" │
> ├──────────────── │     │ data.null_data_source.values is tuple with 2
> elements │  │ Cannot include the given value in a string template:
> string required.

---

Sample code is as below:

```
variable "create_access_only" {
  default = true
  //default = false
}

locals {
  test1 = "new value db"
  test2 = "new value web"
  string_values = "${local.test1},${local.test2}"
  list_test_data = "${split(",", local.string_values)}"
}

output "testlist" {
  value = local.list_test_data
}

variable "data_source_key" {
    default = "test"
}


data "null_data_source" "values" {
  count = "${length(local.list_test_data)}"    
  inputs = {
    data_source_key = "${local.list_test_data[count.index]}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple" {
   for_each = var.create_access_only ? toset(local.list_test_data) : []

    provisioner "local-exec" {
       command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}"



      // command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values}"
      // command = "echo ${each.key} ${each.value.name1} ${each.value.name2}"
      // command = "echo ${each.key}"
      // command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values["${each.key}"]}"
      // command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values["${count.index}"]}"
      // command = "echo ${local.list_test_data}"
    }
}
```

I need to get the data from the datasource response actually.
My requirement is that datasource's 1st value will reflected in resource first loop and so on

Also, I need to get the id from the response of the datasource , I know I am using null_data_source here but my actual script datasource will give me id and other stuff in response

example : `data.datasourcename.varaiablename.namespace[0].id`

Comment: Where is the part of the code for `data "test1"`?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE - thanks for your response, these string I am sending from module, thats why for demo here I have hard code these values in test1 and test2 ... these value consumes in list_string

Comment: Well, `list_string` is not a list of strings the way you are currently assigning a value to it, it should be `list_strings = [local.test1, local.test2]`.

Comment: its a demo script, to make a list I am using it as : list_test_data = "${split(",", local.list_string)}" .. I am using same local variable later on in all the places

Comment: I problem lies in line with code : command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}"

Comment: Here I am missing anything

Comment: I have update the name of variable and remove unwanted code to resolve the confusion

Comment: Why not use `for_each` with the `null_data_source` as well?

Comment: @MarkoE - count.index is working with null_data_source but it need count, for_each do not support - count.index and each.key was throwing some error

Comment: Nope, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this issue is by using the `for_each` with the `null_data_source` as well. However, when running the code, here is one warning:

```
╷
│ Warning: Deprecated Resource
│ 
│   with data.null_data_source.values,
│   on data.tf line 105, in data "null_data_source" "values":
│  105: data "null_data_source" "values" {
│ 
│ The null_data_source was historically used to construct intermediate values to re-use elsewhere in configuration, the same can now be achieved using locals
│ 
│ (and 2 more similar warnings elsewhere)
╵
```

As you can see in the output, the same thing can be achieved with local variables. Here is the code that works:

```
resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple" {
  for_each = var.create_access_only ? toset(local.list_test_data) : []

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values[each.key].outputs["data_source_key"]}"
  }
}

data "null_data_source" "values" {
  for_each = toset(local.list_test_data)
  inputs = {
    data_source_key = each.key
  }
}

variable "create_access_only" {
  default = true
  //default = false
}

variable "data_source_key" {
  default = "test"
}

output "testlist" {
  value = local.list_test_data
}
```

Note that when using `toset` the `each.key` and `each.value` will be the same [1].

Here is the output of the `terraform plan` command:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.null_resource_simple["new value db"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

  # null_resource.null_resource_simple["new value web"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + testlist = [
      + "new value db",
      + "new value web",
    ]
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am getting the same previous error with above code as well which is:

│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on loop.tf line 13, in resource "null_resource" "null_resource_simple":
│   13:     command = "echo ${data.null_data_source.values[each.key].outputs}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.null_data_source.values is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "new value web"
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Comment: @ShubhamJain I fixed the command in the `local-exec` provisioner as I hadn't previously used the `null_data_source`. As you can see, the `outputs` now references the `data_source_key` you defined as an `input` in `null_data_source`.